# How to display the data on list(tableView) for iPhone and grid(collectionView) for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, orientation

I have a code assessment and never think about to something like this; I have to display the data retrieved from an API in two different layouts :

- For iPad; only in landscape mode and in a grid. I will do it with a UIcollectionView
- For iPhone; only in portrait mode and in a list. I will do it with a UItableView or StackView.

The problem is how to implement the logic that populates the collection view or the table view from the view controller. I think I have to use the UITraitCollection but I know if its the better option.

Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do both views with a UICollectionView, adjust layout (cell size) based on device/screenWidth.

Comment: why not use collection view only and two different cells and adjust the size .. Also change the `scrollDirection` from `vertical` and `horizontal` accordingly.

Comment: Both answers are great, but how I know the device and orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the **device** from this method

// 1. request an UITraitCollection instance

```
  let deviceIdiom = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom
```

// 2. check the idiom

```
  switch (deviceIdiom) {

 case .pad:
    print("iPad style UI")
 case .phone:
    print("iPhone and iPod touch style UI")
 case .tv: 
   print("tvOS style UI")
 default:
    print("Unspecified UI idiom")
}
```

And For Orientation use this method:-

```
struct Orientation {
// indicate current device is in the LandScape orientation
  static var isLandscape: Bool {
    get {
        return UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation
            ? UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
            : UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
    }
  }
// indicate current device is in the Portrait orientation
  static var isPortrait: Bool {
    get {
        return UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation
            ? UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
            : UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait
      }
   }
}
```